# How to use xsd.exe with an attribute that contains a colon? (xml:lang)

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, xsd

I get this message:

[image]

There are indeed 2 elements (lsource and gloss) that can contain an attribute named `xml:lang`.

Here is the xsd:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="JMdict_e.dtd" xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="JMdict_e.dtd">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" />
  <xs:element name = "JMdict" >
    < xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "entry" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>                                                                   </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> This element records the information about the source

    language(s) of a loan-word/gairaigo.If the source language is other
   than English, the language is indicated by the xml:lang attribute.
   The element value (if any) is the source word or phrase.
    </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> The xml:lang attribute defines the language(s) from which

    a loanword is drawn.It will be coded using the three-letter language

    code from the ISO 639-2 standard.When absent, the value "eng" (i.e.
   English) is the default value.The bibliographic(B) codes are used. </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> The ls_type attribute indicates whether the lsource element

    fully or partially describes the source word or phrase of the
    loanword.If absent, it will have the implied value of "full".

    Otherwise it will contain "part".  </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> Within each sense will be one or more "glosses", i.e.
    target-language words or phrases which are equivalents to the
    Japanese word.This element would normally be present, however it

    may be omitted in entries which are purely for a cross-reference.
    </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> The xml:lang attribute defines the target language of the

    gloss.It will be coded using the three-letter language code from

    the ISO 639 standard.When absent, the value "eng" (i.e.English)
    is the default value. </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> The sense-information elements provided for additional
    information to be recorded about a sense.Typical usage would

    be to indicate such things as level of currency of a sense, the
    regional variations, etc.
    </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation> The following entity codes are used for common elements within the
various information fields.
</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref= "ent_seq" />
        < xs:element ref= "k_ele" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "r_ele" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "sense" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
      </ xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "ent_seq" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> Entries consist of kanji elements, reading elements,
    general information and sense elements.Each entry must have at
    least one reading element and one sense element.Others are optional.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "k_ele" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> A unique numeric sequence number for each entry
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref= "keb" />
        < xs:element ref= "ke_inf" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "ke_pri" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
      </ xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "keb" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> The kanji element, or in its absence, the reading element, is

    the defining component of each entry.

    The overwhelming majority of entries will have a single kanji

    element associated with a word in Japanese.Where there are
    multiple kanji elements within an entry, they will be orthographical

    variants of the same word, either using variations in okurigana, or
    alternative and equivalent kanji.Common "mis-spellings" may be

    included, provided they are associated with appropriate information
    fields.Synonyms are not included; they may be indicated in the

    cross-reference field associated with the sense element.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "ke_inf" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element will contain a word or short phrase in Japanese

    which is written using at least one non-kana character(usually kanji,
    but can be other characters). The valid characters are

    kanji, kana, related characters such as chouon and kurikaeshi, and
    in exceptional cases, letters from other alphabets.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "ke_pri" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This is a coded information field related specifically to the

    orthography of the keb, and will typically indicate some unusual
    aspect, such as okurigana irregularity.

    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "r_ele" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This and the equivalent re_pri field are provided to record

    information about the relative priority of the entry, and consist

    of codes indicating the word appears in various references which
    can be taken as an indication of the frequency with which the word
    is used.This field is intended for use either by applications which
    want to concentrate on entries of a particular priority, or to

    generate subset files.
    The current values in this field are:
    - news1/2: appears in the "wordfreq" file compiled by Alexandre Girardi
    from the Mainichi Shimbun. (See the Monash ftp archive for a copy.)

    Words in the first 12,000 in that file are marked "news1" and words
    in the second 12,000 are marked "news2".
    - ichi1/2: appears in the "Ichimango goi bunruishuu", Senmon Kyouiku

    Publishing, Tokyo, 1998.  (The entries marked "ichi2" were
    demoted from ichi1 because they were observed to have low
    frequencies in the WWW and newspapers.)
    - spec1 and spec2: a small number of words use this marker when they
    are detected as being common, but are not included in other lists.
    - gai1/2: common loanwords, based on the wordfreq file.
    - nfxx: this is an indicator of frequency-of-use ranking in the
    wordfreq file. "xx" is the number of the set of 500 words in which
    the entry can be found, with "01" assigned to the first 500, "02"

    to the second, and so on. (The entries with news1, ichi1, spec1, spec2
    and gai1 values are marked with a "(P)" in the EDICT and EDICT2

    files.)

    The reason both the kanji and reading elements are tagged is because
    on occasions a priority is only associated with a particular
    kanji/reading pair.
    </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation>                                                                   </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="reb"/>
        <xs:element ref="re_nokanji" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="re_restr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="re_inf" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="re_pri" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="reb" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> The reading element typically contains the valid readings
    of the word(s) in the kanji element using modern kanadzukai.
    Where there are multiple reading elements, they will typically be
    alternative readings of the kanji element.In the absence of a
   kanji element, i.e. in the case of a word or phrase written

    entirely in kana, these elements will define the entry.

    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "re_nokanji" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> this element content is restricted to kana and related
    characters such as chouon and kurikaeshi.Kana usage will be

    consistent between the keb and reb elements; e.g. if the keb

    contains katakana, so too will the reb.

    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "re_restr" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element, which will usually have a null value, indicates
    that the reb, while associated with the keb, cannot be regarded
    as a true reading of the kanji. It is typically used for words
    such as foreign place names, gairaigo which can be in kanji or

    katakana, etc.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "re_inf" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element is used to indicate when the reading only applies

    to a subset of the keb elements in the entry. In its absence, all
    readings apply to all kanji elements.The contents of this element
    must exactly match those of one of the keb elements.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "re_pri" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> General coded information pertaining to the specific reading.

    Typically it will be used to indicate some unusual aspect of
    the reading. </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "sense" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> See the comment on ke_pri above. </xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation>                                                                   </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref= "stagk" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "stagr" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "pos" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "xref" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "ant" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "field" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "misc" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "s_inf" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "lsource" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "dial" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
        < xs:element ref= "gloss" minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" />
      </ xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "stagk" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> The sense element will record the translational equivalent

    of the Japanese word, plus other related information. Where there

    are several distinctly different meanings of the word, multiple
    sense elements will be employed.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "stagr" type= "xs:string" />
  < xs:element name = "xref" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> These elements, if present, indicate that the sense is restricted
    to the lexeme represented by the keb and/or reb. </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "ant" type= "xs:string" >
    < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element is used to indicate a cross-reference to another
    entry with a similar or related meaning or sense. The content of

    this element is typically a keb or reb element in another entry. In some

    cases a keb will be followed by a reb and/or a sense number to provide

    a precise target for the cross-reference.Where this happens, a JIS
    "centre-dot" (0x2126) is placed between the components of the

    cross-reference.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "pos" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element is used to indicate another entry which is an
    antonym of the current entry/sense.The content of this element
   must exactly match that of a keb or reb element in another entry.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "field" type= "xs:string" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> Part-of-speech information about the entry/sense.Should use

   appropriate entity codes.In general where there are multiple senses

   in an entry, the part-of-speech of an earlier sense will apply to

   later senses unless there is a new part-of-speech indicated.

   </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "misc" type= "xs:string" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> Information about the field of application of the entry/sense.
   When absent, general application is implied.Entity coding for

   specific fields of application. </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "lsource" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> This element is used for other relevant information about

   the entry/sense.As with part-of-speech, information will usually
   apply to several senses.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name = "xml:lang" type= "xs:string" default="eng"/>
          <xs:attribute name = "ls_type" type= "xs:string" />

         < xs:attribute name = "ls_wasei" type= "xs:string" />

       </ xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "dial" type= "xs:string" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> The ls_wasei attribute indicates that the Japanese word

   has been constructed from words in the source language, and
   not from an actual phrase in that language. Most commonly used to

   indicate "waseieigo". </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "gloss" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> For words specifically associated with regional dialects in
   Japanese, the entity code for that dialect, e.g.ksb for Kansaiben.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType mixed = "true" >

     < xs:choice minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs= "unbounded" >

       < xs:element ref= "pri" />

     </ xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name = "xml:lang" type= "xs:string" default="eng"/>
      <xs:attribute name = "g_gend" type= "xs:string" />

   </ xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "pri" type= "xs:string" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> The g_gend attribute defines the gender of the gloss (typically
   a noun in the target language.When absent, the gender is either
   not relevant or has yet to be provided.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name = "s_inf" type= "xs:string" >

   < xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> These elements highlight particular target-language words which
   are strongly associated with the Japanese word. The purpose is to
   establish a set of target-language words which can effectively be

   used as head-words in a reverse target-language/Japanese relationship.
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ref="xml:space"` rather than `name="xml:space"`. Because the attribute is defined in the schema for the XML namespace, you need to reference it, rather than declaring it locally.

You also need to import the schema for the XML namespace, but you've done that correctly.